# Get Child Nodes attribute value using DOM parser in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, xml-parsing

I need to get the value of `"templatedata"` (`RK1S`) using `JavaScript`.

```
<additional_info>
<Param name="srno" value="B4745" />
<Param name="Device" value="Opn" />
<Param name="Support" value="0" />
<Param name="templatedata" value="Rk1S"/>
</additional_info>
```

I tried with the following script but I'm getting `undefined`.

```js
var text=" <additional_info>
    <Param name="srno" value="B4745" />
    <Param name="Device" value="Opn" />
    <Param name="Support" value="0" />
    <Param name="templatedata" value="Rk1S"/>
    </additional_info>";

if (window.DOMParser) {
  parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
} else {
  xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async = false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(text); 
} 


var txt;
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("additional_info");
alert(x[0].value);
var y=x.getAttribute("Param name")
txt = y.nodeValue;
alert(txt);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check escape characters in your string. You need single quotes, backticks or backslashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is `querySelector` for the element you want, which can be selected with `Param[name="templatedata"]`. Use a template literal instead of double quotes to define a string over multiple lines, and use `getAttribute('value')` instead of `.value`, because `.value` only works for input-like elements:

```js
var text = `<additional_info>
<Param name="srno" value="B4745" />
<Param name="Device" value="Opn" />
<Param name="Support" value="0" />
<Param name="templatedata" value="Rk1S"/>
</additional_info>`;

let parser;
let xmlDoc;
if (window.DOMParser) {
  parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
} else {
  xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async = false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
}
const param = xmlDoc.querySelector('Param[name="templatedata"]');
console.log(param.getAttribute('value'));
```